# Speed up gaussian elimination step with numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I'm currently working on implementing the Simplex algorithm and at the moment want to speed up the process.

In the gaussian elimination step I'm using

```
    # gausian elimination
    rang = list(range(0,leaving_row))
    rang.extend(range(leaving_row+1,self.matrix.shape[0]))

    facs = -self.matrix[:, entering] / self.matrix[leaving_row, entering]
    facs[leaving_row] = 0
    for row in rang:
        self.matrix[row] += facs[row] * self.matrix[leaving_row]

    self.matrix[leaving_row] /= self.matrix[leaving_row, entering]
```

What it basically does is one gaussian step in way that the `leaving_row` has a 1 at the end in the `entering` column.

Is there any way of speeding up the for loop? Any fancy way of using matrix multiplication here?

Thanks for any ideas in advance.

My matrix shape is:
(1105, 2107)

One of these gaussian eliminations take about 0.009s on my laptop. I would like to be able to use my program on bigger instances therefore I would like to speed it up as much as possible.

**Edit**
I also tried to replace the loop by:

```
l_r = self.matrix[leaving_row]
l_r_m = np.broadcast_to([l_r],self.matrix.shape)
self.matrix += l_r_m*facs[:,np.newaxis]
```

That seems to be a bit faster (around 0.007 instead of 0.009) but it also looks quite odd with this huge `broadcast_to` function.

Comment: Have you tried implicit broadcasting with `self.matrix+=facs[:,np.newaxis]*self.matrix[leaving_row,np.newaxis,:]`?

Comment: Looks like it has the same timing but yeah looks a bit nicer

Comment: I don't think you will get much more speed out of this. Looks like you don't need `rang`, which seems like it could be slow. You could also try to pre-allocate `facs`.